# Modificando tamanho da imagem dentro do conteudo wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Para os amigos que entende de wordpress, poderia me da uma ajuda?
preciso modificar o tamanho das imagens dentro do meu content, imagem dentro das postagens.

Peguei uma função de redimensionar imagem [aqui](https://gist.github.com/seedprod/1367237) e funciona muito bem, minha dificuldade é para usar essa função dentro do meu functions para redimensionar o tamanho dos thumbs dentro do post.

Tentei elaborar uma função mais não está funcionando, alguém poderia me dizer como funcionar essa função?

```
function resizeThumb($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr){
$image = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb = vt_resize( $image, '', 850, 600, true );
$html = '<img src="' . $thumb[url] . '" alt="' . $alt . '" class="img-responsive" />';
return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'resizeThumb', 10, 5 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Já tentou usar a função `set_post_thumbnail_size()` do wordpress ?

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true ); // width, height, crop
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size

Imagino que ela deva servir para o que vc deseja.